# Can I speed up this query by using EXISTS instead of a JOIN?

Tags: mysql, join, exists, sql-optimization

I have the below query, which is running on a db with over 24 million rows, as such it is taking too long and timing out.

I was hoping to rewrite this to use an EXISTS to try and save on performance.

Is this possible?

```
    SELECT DISTINCT e.EmployeeKey,
                e.EmployeeId,
                dd.Name,
                ed.Text,
                ed.Value,
                ed.ValidFrom,
                ed.ValidTo
FROM EmployeeData ed
INNER JOIN DataDefinition dd ON ed.DataDefinitionId=dd.DataDefinitionId
INNER JOIN Employee e ON ed.EmployeeId=e.EmployeeId
WHERE 1 = 1
  AND (ed.ValidTo > CONVERT(date,GETDATE())
       OR ed.ValidTo IS NULL)
  --AND e.EmployeeKey IN ('NBK8GLU')
  --AND e.EmployeeId IN ('')
ORDER BY 2
```

Comment: Instead of rewriting the query, let's look at why your query might be so slow.  Can you edit your question to show us your table layout and index definitions?  Some proper indexing will probably solve the problem.

Comment: Sadly I don't have access to this as it's not my db, I've just been tasked at this time with pulling some data from it...

Comment: If the problem is that the table is not indexed, then rewriting the query isn't going to do any good.  The only other thing I can see is that maybe `ed.ValidTo` is indexed, but the `CONVERT(date,GETDATE())` call is not able to use that index.  Indexing is a crucial part of SQL optimization and without knowing what the indexing is, you're going to be making shots in the dark.

Answer (score 0):

The first and more classic approach is to break the Or with union. Something like that:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    e.EmployeeKey,
    e.EmployeeId,
    dd.Name,
    ed.Text,
    ed.Value,
    ed.ValidFrom,
    ed.ValidTo
FROM 
    EmployeeData ed
    INNER JOIN DataDefinition dd ON ed.DataDefinitionId = dd.DataDefinitionId
    INNER JOIN Employee e ON ed.EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId
WHERE
    (ed.ValidTo > CONVERT(date,GETDATE())    
ORDER BY 2

Union

SELECT DISTINCT 
    e.EmployeeKey,
    e.EmployeeId,
    dd.Name,
    ed.Text,
    ed.Value,
    ed.ValidFrom,
    ed.ValidTo
FROM 
    EmployeeData ed
    INNER JOIN DataDefinition dd ON ed.DataDefinitionId = dd.DataDefinitionId
    INNER JOIN Employee e ON ed.EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId
WHERE
    ( ed.ValidTo IS NULL)
ORDER BY 2
```

I would also try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    e.EmployeeKey,
    e.EmployeeId,
    dd.Name,
    ed.Text,
    ed.Value,
    ed.ValidFrom,
    ed.ValidTo
FROM 
    EmployeeData ed
    INNER JOIN DataDefinition dd ON ed.DataDefinitionId = dd.DataDefinitionId
    INNER JOIN Employee e ON ed.EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId
WHERE
    ( IsNull( ed.ValidTo, DATEADD( day, 1, GetDate() ) ) > CONVERT( date, GETDATE() )    
ORDER BY 2
```